# How to lock a static text in the margin in ConTeXt?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, marginpar, context-mkiv

Even though I have a some manuals at hand I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.
Within an invoice I created with ConTeXt (MkIV) I have placed a short paragraph in the right margin. This paragraph is not be changed and I would love to have it locked at a certain vertical distance. But whenever I add new lines to my main text (in the text field) this paragraph in the margin moves down. I can fix it again by adjusting "[line=x]" but I wonder if this could be locked?

Here is how I wrote my paragraph:

`\inright[style=normal,line=7]{Text in paragraph.}`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the marginblocks mechanism. Margin blocks are margin floats
which stack the content from the top downwards. You can use the `top` key to
provide a fixed offset for the first margin block. Here's an example:

```
\setupmarginblocks
    [width=2cm,
     top={\blank[8*line]}]

\starttext

\input knuth

\startmarginblock
    Text in paragraph.
\stopmarginblock

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Another possibility is the very flexible [Layers mechanism.](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers)

Comment: Dear Marco, thanks a lot! That is exactly what I have been looking for.